# Element type is invalid: undefined - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amp-html

I have the following error: `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of 'Screens/Enjoy.js'.`

With following code:

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { renderToString, AMP } from 'react-amp-template'

class Enjoy extends Component {
render() {
        const { Title, Link, Carousel } = AMP;
const amppage = (
            <Fragment>
                <Title>Hello guys :)</Title>
                <Link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost" />
                    <h1>Hello World</h1>
                    <Carousel lightbox width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" type="slides">
                        <amp-img src="image.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
                        <amp-img src="image.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
                        <amp-img src="image.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>

                    </Carousel>
            </Fragment>
        );
        return(
                amppage
              )
    }
}
export default Enjoy
```

I'm using "react": "15.3.1" and "react-dom": "15.3.1"

Tell me, please, what could be the matter? I looked at similar errors, but their solutions did not help me.
Thanks a lot in advance!

upd: 
I am very sorry, I missed the `render()` method when I copied it in the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put constants declarations inside a class body. Either move constants outside the class or define the property as a class property as I have done.

Also, the spelling of word ***default*** is wrong. Correct that as well

**OPTION 1:**

```
const amppage = (
  <Fragment>
    <Title>Hello guys :)</Title>
    <Link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost" />
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <Carousel lightbox width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" type="slides">
      <amp-img src="image.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
      <amp-img src="image.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
      <amp-img src="image.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>

    </Carousel>
  </Fragment>
);
class Enjoy extends Component {
    render() {
            return amppage;
    }
}
export default Enjoy;
```

**OPTION 2:**

```
class Enjoy extends Component {
    amppage = (
        <Fragment>
          <Title>Hello guys :)</Title>
          <Link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost" />
          <h1>Hello World</h1>
          <Carousel lightbox width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" type="slides">
            <amp-img src="image.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
            <amp-img src="image.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
            <amp-img src="image.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>

          </Carousel>
        </Fragment>
    );
    render() {
            return this.amppage;
    }
}
export default Enjoy;
```

Comment: Sorry :(, copied code with an error! I have a `render` method, updated code

Comment: @A.Burdonskaya answer updated, it should work. See my sample that demonstrates this: https://codesandbox.io/s/047051y29w

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `class` components, you need a `render` method:

```
class Enjoy extends Component {
    const amppage = (
            <Fragment>
                <Title>Hello guys :)</Title>
                <Link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost" />
                    <h1>Hello World</h1>
                    <Carousel lightbox width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" type="slides">
                        <amp-img src="image.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
                        <amp-img src="image.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
                        <amp-img src="image.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>

                    </Carousel>
            </Fragment>
        );
    render() {
        return amppage;
    }
}
export default Enjoy;
```

However, since you are not using lifecycle methods, you can use a functional component instead:

```
const Enjoy = (props) => {
const amppage = (
            <Fragment>
                <Title>Hello guys :)</Title>
                <Link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost" />
                    <h1>Hello World</h1>
                    <Carousel lightbox width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" type="slides">
                        <amp-img src="image.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
                        <amp-img src="image.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
                        <amp-img src="image.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>

                    </Carousel>
            </Fragment>
        );
        return(
                amppage
              )
}
export default Enjoy;
```

If you use a functional component, then you can simply return (as you were doing).  Because the body of the functional component is the same as the body of the `render` method in class components.

There error you are seeing is telling you that when React is calling the `render` method, it expects a component back, but it is currently `undefined` because there is no body of the `render`.

Also, support for `Fragment` was not introduced until React version 16.2.0.  So, on 15.x you would need to wrap in a `div`:

```
class Enjoy extends Component {
    const amppage = (
            <div>
                <Title>Hello guys :)</Title>
                <Link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost" />
                    <h1>Hello World</h1>
                    <Carousel lightbox width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" type="slides">
                        <amp-img src="image.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
                        <amp-img src="image.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
                        <amp-img src="image.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>

                    </Carousel>
            </div>
        );
    render() {
        return amppage;
    }
}
export default Enjoy;
```

Comment: Sorry :(, copied code with an error! I have a `render` method, updated code

Comment: Maybe it is the misspelling then?  `defalut` should be `default`.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer.  I think it is due to `Fragment` not being in the version you are using.

Comment: I am very ashamed, no, in my code everything is correct. This is another error when copying...

Comment: I replaced the fragment with a div, and now I have the following error: `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

Comment: Where are `Title`, `Link` and `Carousel` coming from?  Are they included in the imports?

Comment: Please check the updated code. Checked it for errors and added the missing items (`Title, Link and Carousel` included now)

Comment: Still includes `Fragment`.  But maybe your version if AMP is not compatible with React 15.x?

Comment: As far as I understand, there are no other problems, so yes, this is most likely. Thank you very much for your time and help, I will go update my project and return to this issue.